# Accessing to User.Identity in Application_Start()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to access to `User.Identity.Name` in my `Application_Start()`

i will use this to get data from my DbContext

is it possible to do something like this? can i do better?

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        using (MyApp.ContextDB context = new MyApp.ContextDB())
        {
            var uid = context.SomeDBSet.Where(x => x.WinID == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            Application["uid"] = uid ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you can use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: `Application["uid"]` makes no sense. The `Application` is by definition shared by all its users. I think you're looking for `Session` or `Request` scope.

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea to make identity of user making a first request to somehow impact behavior of whole application.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, that's most likely not the idea. :)

Comment: there are no `User` item in `HttpContext` :/

Comment: @Salem - there is *absolutely no* good scenarios when user's identity can be used in App_start - so ASP.Net runtime does not provide you one to protect you from yourself - see SLacks' answer.

Comment: I whant to retrieve User data from my DB which match with `User.Identity.Name` and make it global. so how to do that? :(

Comment: This is a terrible terrible idea.

Comment: @Salem: That doesn't make any sense.  There is no global user.

Comment: i know that, but i whant to do somethig simpler, I whant just retrieve data from DB (when my app starts) an store it in a globlal variable (like `Session['xxx']`) to have access to my data from anywhere.
EDIT : I whant to pass `User.Identity.Name` to my db query as param

Comment: @Salem: You don't want to do that when the app starts.  You could do that when creating each user's session.

Answer (score 8):

There is no user in `Application_Start`.

`Application_Start` runs when setting up the application, before any requests come in.

It sounds like you actually want to set **HttpContext** state in `Application_BeginRequest`.
(not `Application` state, which is global and is shared among all requests)